# Ubuntu 18.04 mishap during installtion dell 5577 (Not black or blank screen)

Tags: 18.04

I have a dell 5577. I recently wanted to get ubuntu for my laptop so i flashed the iso image from a pendrive and successfully installed ubuntu upto the part where it says restart now. i clicked restart and my laptop froze. I waited for a decent 10 mins but still it was the same so i force rebooted it. And now it has quite some problems. Such as fucntion keys not working for volume or brightness and headphone jack not working. At first ubuntu wouldnt even boot from the grub menu but i added "acpi=off" by pressing e on grub menu to the linux line so it atleast boots it up for me now.
Should i try to uninstall and reinstall or can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: You may be able to salvage the installation by doing `sudo apt install -f` and/or `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Perhaps a few times until nothing happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: hi. i executed them. it asked me to create a password and when i reboot it i should give it while booting. If im not wrong it said it was for the "MOK"... not sure exactly.. when i rebooted before the grub launcher i got option saying continue boot and enroll "MOK".. i clicked on continue boot and it took me back to the usual ubuntu. Should i have clicked enroll MOK and would it have asked for the password that I was asked to create?